# Understanding Foreign Key Constraints in MYSQL

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys, constraints

I am really struggling to understand how foreign keys work, though I can see that they are a very useful tool.

I have a table called `seasons` which includes a column `season_id` which is the primary key. There are a few other columns too.

I have a second table called `dates` which includes columns called `hid`, `date` and `season_id` (and a few others). The primary key contains both `hid` and `date`. `season_id` has a foreign key constraint `ON DELETE SET NULL` and `ON UPDATE CASCADE`.

Does this mean that if I delete a row in `dates`, `season_id` will be set to `null` in `seasons`? Or the other way around?

What I need to happen is that when I delete a row in `dates`, `seasons` is not affected. But if I delete a row in `seasons`, `season_id` should be set to `null` in `dates`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's the other way around. A foreign key defines a dependency relationship: the `season_id` in `dates` has to refer to an existing row in `seasons`. So you can't delete a row in `seasons` if there are any rows in `dates` that refer to it. The `ON DELETE` option specifies that if you delete the row, you'll replace the reference to it with `NULL`, to maintain this requirement.

So what you need to happen will happen.

Comment: So far, so good. But when I try to delete a date from a season, I hit a problem. I want to keep the date row in the table but set season_id to null.

The query is
UPDATE dates SET season_id = 'NULL' WHERE hid = '$hid' AND date = '$value'

However I then get the error message
Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`lithot_extranet/dates`, CONSTRAINT `dates_ibfk_19` FOREIGN KEY (`season_id`) REFERENCES `seasons` (`season_id`) ON DELETE SET NULL ON UPDATE CASCADE)

Comment: Don't put `NULL` in quotes.

Comment: It's so simple when you know how! I think I'm under way again, so a green tick for Barmar. perdigueiro deserves one too, but I don't know if the system allows two of them. Thanks, guys.

Answer (score 0):

Basic definition is: a foreign key is cross-reference related data across tables.

In you case you have the table `seasons` with the following data (guessing here) and the table `months`. The foreign key is `season` the table month can have an `ON DELETE CASCADE` clause that will apply the DELETE action to the records affected by the deletion of a season. So if you'd erase *Winter* on table `seasons` the records with the respective foreign key *1* would be deleted and we would lose Christmas.

```
    season_id --- season_name || month_id --- season --- month_name
       1      --- Winter      ||    1     ---   1          January
       2      --- Spring      ||    ...
       3      --- Summer      ||    7     ---   3          July 
       4      --- Autumn      ||    8     ---   4          September
```